# Building a non-default constructor in Julia

Tags: julia

How do I build a constructor in Julia with fewer inputs than values? I have an Int64 array of numbers where each number represents 24 boolean values. The best situation would be that I could send in the array and get back a composite type with arrays of each component. Here is the code I've tried.

```
type Status
   Valve1::Array{Bool}
   Valve2::Array{Bool}
   Valve3::Array{Bool}
   Valve4::Array{Bool}
   Valve5::Array{Bool}
   Valve6::Array{Bool}
   Valve7::Array{Bool}
   Valve8::Array{Bool}

   # Constructor for Status type
   function Status(vals::Array{Int64})
   l = int64(length(vals))

   Valve1 = Array(Bool,l)
   Valve2 = Array(Bool,l)
   Valve3 = Array(Bool,l)
   Valve4 = Array(Bool,l)
   Valve5 = Array(Bool,l)
   Valve6 = Array(Bool,l)
   Valve7 = Array(Bool,l)
   Valve8 = Array(Bool,l)

   # Parse Inputs
   for i=1:l
      # Byte 1
      Valve1[i] = vals[i] & 2^(1-1) > 0
      Valve2[i] = vals[i] & 2^(2-1) > 0
      Valve3[i] = vals[i] & 2^(3-1) > 0
      Valve4[i] = vals[i] & 2^(4-1) > 0
      Valve5[i] = vals[i] & 2^(5-1) > 0
      Valve6[i] = vals[i] & 2^(6-1) > 0
      Valve7[i] = vals[i] & 2^(7-1) > 0
      Valve8[i] = vals[i] & 2^(8-1) > 0
   end # End of conversion

   new(Valve1,Valve2,Valve3,Valve4,Valve5,Valve6,Valve7,Valve8)

   end # End of constructor
end # End of type
```

This results in a `no method convert(Type{Bool},Array{Bool,1})` error. I tried to instantiate it with `statuses = Status(StatusW)` where StatusW is an Int64 array of values.

Useful references: [Types](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/) and [Constructors](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/manual/constructors/) section of the [Julia documentation](http://docs.julialang.org)

Comment: Changing the definition to `Valve1::Array{Bool,1}` results in a similar error.

`no method convert(Type{Array{Bool,1}},Bool)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declarations needs to be as follows.

```
Valve1::Vector{Bool}
```

Another factor contributing to my confusion was that `new(Valve1,...)` should be the last thing in the constructor. I had added debugging `println()`lines after the `new(Valve1,...)` causing the type to return *Nothing*.

Tim Holy on the Julia Google Groups forum provided the [solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/oPT7WjHwN5k).

The full example should look like this.

```
type Status
    Valve1::VectorBool}
    Valve2::Vector{Bool}
    Valve3::Vector{Bool}
    Valve4::Vector{Bool}
    Valve5::Vector{Bool}
    Valve6::Vector{Bool}
    Valve7::Vector{Bool}
    Valve8::Vector{Bool}

    # Constructor for Status type
    function Status(vals::Array{Int64})
        l = int64(length(vals))

        Valve1 = Array(Bool,l)
        Valve2 = Array(Bool,l)
        Valve3 = Array(Bool,l)
        Valve4 = Array(Bool,l)
        Valve5 = Array(Bool,l)
        Valve6 = Array(Bool,l)
        Valve7 = Array(Bool,l)
        Valve8 = Array(Bool,l)

        # Parse Inputs
        for i=1:l
            # Byte 1
            Valve1[i] = vals[i] & 2^(1-1) > 0
            Valve2[i] = vals[i] & 2^(2-1) > 0
            Valve3[i] = vals[i] & 2^(3-1) > 0
            Valve4[i] = vals[i] & 2^(4-1) > 0
            Valve5[i] = vals[i] & 2^(5-1) > 0
            Valve6[i] = vals[i] & 2^(6-1) > 0
            Valve7[i] = vals[i] & 2^(7-1) > 0
            Valve8[i] = vals[i] & 2^(8-1) > 0
        end # End of conversion

        new(Valve1,Valve2,Valve3,Valve4,Valve5,Valve6,Valve7,Valve8)

    end # End of constructor
end # End of type
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct, but unfortunately it is quite hard to understand the generic error messages in Julia.

The problem is that you declare your fields as the partially initialized `Array{Bool, N}`, and that does not seem to work when you try to call the constructor with `Array{Bool, 1}`.

The right solution is to declare the type to contain a fully initialized type `Array{Bool,1}` or use the alias `Vector{Bool}`.

What version of Julia are you using? The code you posted works for me on the latest Julia master, and I think this might have been fixed when https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4026 solved.

Comment: Version 0.2.0 (2013-11-16 23:44 UTC)